# Binary Search Tree doesn't insert after certain number of nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, insert, binary-search-tree

I implemented the insert the insert function as follows.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data

def insert(self, data):
    if self.data is None:
        self.data = data
    else:
        if (data < self.data):
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        elif (data > self.data):
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.data.insert(data)
```

and I gave the following inputs

```
root = Node(8)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(1)
root.insert(6)
root.insert(5)
```

but it throws an error after root.insert(6).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\BST.py", line 45, in <module>
    root.insert(5)
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\BST.py", line 15, in insert
    self.left.insert(data)
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\BST.py", line 20, in insert
    self.data.insert(data)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

I have tried with other numbers as well, but I still get the error. Can anyone give me a reason for that? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: replace your `self.data.insert(data)` with `self.right.insert(data)`

Comment: Thank you very much. It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `self.data.insert(data)` (line 20) with `self.right.insert(data)`